# Related to plancherel identity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I recently stumbled over the following identity for Schwartz functions $f$:

$$\pi \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{f(x)}{|x|} dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \widehat{f(x)}
\frac{1}{|x|^2} dx. $$

It almost looks like something derived from Plancherel's identity but I did not see how it can be proven. Does anybody of you know where it comes from?

Comment: The right hand side is simply $\langle f, \mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{|x|^2}\right)\rangle$. Can you compute the distribution that is the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{|x|^2}$ ?

Comment: The Fourier transform of $1/|x|^2$ exists as a distribution, do you know about distributions?

Comment: @onamoonlessnight no, unfortunately not. could you explain me how to do this?